# How do I run a py file with pico in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I got this when I tried to open a `.py` file on the terminal line I edited in pico:

```
lightning@rigel5:~$ ./hello.py
bash: ./hello.py: Permission denied
```

How can I easily open a `.py` file from the pico editor in the terminal and run it in the python interpreter?

Comment: Where is the file located? Did you create the file you are trying to run?

Comment: As I can see, in the command that you are entering, you're trying to **run** it but not **edit** it. Normally, you can to open the file with the editor that you want to, adding the file as a parameter. e.g. using the *Geany* editor: `geany main.c`

Comment: yes I created it and it is in the Home folder

Comment: use chmod 755 command

Comment: ok lets try that now

Comment: @lucio the files are being edited in pico and then Im trying to run them with the python interpreter

Comment: @microarm whats the syntax for that.... chmod 755?

Comment: The `chmod` command is to give you permissions to run the file. enter `man chmod` for more information

Comment: sounds fair. not sure how to do that

Comment: @lightning You has marked question as *solved* by marking the answer as accepted. So, is not necessary to add it to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to open the file with Pico:**

In the terminal enter `pico file` where *file* is the path and the name of the file that you're trying to open with the editor.

**How to run the python script from terminal:**

There are a couples of ways to do it, one of them is:

1. Give execution permissions to the file entering `chmod +x file.py`
2. Run the script with `./file.py`

Another way is using the python interpreter:

1. Enter `python file.py`

**NOTE:** In all commands replace *file* with your're file name

Answer (score 1):

if your file is in home, use

```
sudo chmod 755 "your_file.py"
./"your_file.py"
```

Comment: what does the 755 mean, Microarm?

Comment: thanks microarm, been having problems with this and can now use this question to practice

Comment: the numeric notation is used to change the permission for a certain file for owner, group and others.. you may google for it if you are interested

Comment: To be precise, 755 means: the user can RWX, the group and others can RX. Where R=read, W=write and X=execute.